# Get an element from a hashmap by == operator, rather than .equal in java

Tags: java, hashmap, containskey

I have a hashmap and I want to find a key by reference. I found out that the `get(key)` method uses `.equal()` to find a key. But I need it to use `==` to find it by reference.
For example in the below code:

```
HashMap<List, String> myMap = new HashMap<List, String>();
List<String> pets = new ArrayList<>();
pets.add("cat");
pets.add("dog");
    
myMap.put(pets, "pets");
    
List<String> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.add("cat");
animals.add("dog");
    
var alreadyExists = myMap.containsKey(animals); //I want this to return false
if(!alreadyExists) {
    myMap.put(animals, "pets");
}
    
System.out.println(myMap.size());  //and therefore, I want this to print 2!
```

As I have commented, I need the `alreadyExists` to be `false`.

I am new to java but in c# you could easily do such things with something like:

`var alreadyExists = myMap.containsKey(a => a == animals);`

Is there any way to do such things in Java, as I do **not** want to override the `equal()` method!

Comment: use IdentityHashMap instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has a class called [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), which does exactly what you want - it compares the reference rather than using equals().

Comment: You need to be careful with a mutable list as a key, as explains here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182116/java-using-hashmap-with-list-as-key

Comment: @RickyLim `IdentityHashMap` avoids the problem of a mutable class as a key, since `System.identityHashCode()` is used for keying and won't change.

Comment: Is there such thing also for a List? I mean to find an item in a list with `list.contains()` which searches for the item with its reference.